# Searching for the 'correct' solution when using pseudoinverse

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a system of ordinary differential equations `x'(t) = Lx(t)`, and I want to find the frequency space behaviour while accounting for initial conditions at `x(t=0)`. I can do this in two ways:

1. propagate the equations in the time domain, then do a (one-sided) Fourier transform; or
2. Do a Laplace transform of the equation of motion, to obtain the linear equation `(1j * w * ident - L) X(w) = x(t=0)` and solve this directly (note that I have restricted the Laplace variable to be purely imaginary numbers).

This is done easily with:

```
def resolvant(w,L):

    R = np.linalg.inv(1j * ident * w - L)

    return R
```

This works for all points where `1j * ident * w-L` is non singular. Now my matrix `L` has a single zero eigenvalue with the rest of its eigenvalues complex. Therefore the resolvant is singular only at the point `w=0`.

I can replace the inverse function with a pseudo inverse at this point:

```
def resolvant(w,L):
    if w !=0:
        R = np.linalg.inv(1j * ident * w - L)
    else:
        R = np.linalg.pinv(- L)
    return R
```

In many situations this works, however in a number of important cases the pseudo inverse approach differs from that found through the time domain approach. Is there a way of constraining the pseudo-inverse to give the correct behaviour at `w=0`?

**Edit:**
Minimal Working example

```
import numpy as np

#construct matrix on for the RHS of equation
L = np.array([[0,-1.j,0,1.j,0,0,0,0,0],[-1.j,-0.5,0,0,1.j,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1.j,0,0,0],[1.j,0,0,-0.5,-1.j,0,0,0,0],[0,1.j,0,-1.j,-1.,0,0,0,0],[ 0,0,1.j,0,0,-0.5,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.j,0],[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.j,-0.5,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]])

#initial vector is given as:

x0=np.zeros(L.shape[0])
x0[0] = 1

#calculate the pseudo inverse and resultant vector:
R = np.linalg.pinv(-L)

res = np.dot(R, x0)
print(res)
```

this code yields

```
array([  5.00000000e-01 +1.04874666e-17j,
     1.74736751e-16 -3.33333333e-01j,
     1.23748154e-16 +6.69892995e-17j,
     6.13265296e-17 +3.33333333e-01j,
     3.33333333e-01 +2.70701098e-17j,
     1.24640823e-17 +9.26971489e-17j,
     0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,
     0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j,   0.00000000e+00 +0.00000000e+00j])
```

in contrast we can calculate the same object in the time domain by propagating the ODE and integrating to the end point (code not shown here for compactness), which gives:

```
array([[  1.25024870+0.j        ],
   [  0.00000000-0.49999962j],
   [  0.00000000+0.j        ],
   [  0.00000000+0.49999962j],
   [  1.00000113+0.j        ],
   [  0.00000000+0.j        ],
   [  0.00000000+0.j        ],
   [  0.00000000+0.j        ],
   [ 47.75025018+0.j        ]])
```

clearly there is a considerable disparity between the results.

Comment: really need a [mcve] here.  "a number of important cases" doesn't give us anything to test against.

Comment: Good point. See edit above!

Comment: Try to ask at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com? You can write the mathematics equation with Latex there. This might be a math problem instead of a programming problem.